# Setting UI objects with many widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 5.5.1. I have a `MainWindow` which is created manually with the code. It has a `QListWidget` and `QStackedWidget`. Also, I have 5 widgets with `*.ui` files made in form design. The problem is that I don't know how to set fields for objects on forms from `MainWindow.cpp`.

Here are the first lines of pages.h :

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui
{
    class settings;
    class textCreating;
    class databasework;
    class AutoMode;
    class ManualMode;
}

class settings : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    settings(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~settings();
    static Ui::settings *ui; //It was private and not static at first
private:
};

//other classes//
//...//
```

And in pages.cpp :

```
settings::settings(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

And MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    //code here//

    settings::ui->firstAddedParamLabel->setVisible(true);
}
```

So, when I compile, I get :

> error: 'Ui::settings* settings::ui' is a static data member; it can
>   only be  initialized at its definition
>        settings::settings(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::settings)

And it points to `ui(new Ui::settings)`. My question is, **how to set/get UI fields?** I can't fully understand. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve by make it public and static, maybe there is another way around that will achieve the same thing

Comment: I couldn't use private member Ui::settings in MainWindow, for example. So I made it public. After this I've got an error saying I can't set static member Ui::settings.

Comment: Why are you trying to manipulate `Ui::settings` from `MainWindow`?

Answer (score 2):

your "ui" member shouldn't be static. For what reason did you decided to do that? You could even use it as a simple class scoped member, like:

```
#include <QWidget>    
#include "ui_settings.h"

class settings : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  settings(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
  {// move this to cpp...
    ui.setupUi(this);
  }
  virtual ~settings();

public:
  Ui::settings ui;
};
```

And to use it, you can simple add it as member of your MainWindow class.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
  {
    _settings = new settings(this);
    setCentralWidget(_settings); // You may also add it somewhere else in your layout, of course.

    _settings->ui.firstAddedParamLabel->setVisible(true);
  }

private:
  settings* _settings;
};
```

Personally, I don't think that it is very beautiful to expose the entire `Ui::settings` class as public. I would also recommend to keep a clean Code style and use correctly camel-case typed and more robust class names.

e.g.: `settings` => `SettingsWidget`
and for the generated UI class maybe: `ui::settings` => `Ui::SettingsWidgetForm`

This makes it easier to keep the difference between generated and self written classes.

Comment: I did it because I've got error: invalid use of non-static data member 'settings::ui' Ui::settings *ui;

Comment: See my update about the usage in your MainWindow, please :-)

Comment: Not sure if I got it right... So should I move constructor of class to header? And then set all main windows's members in constructor? My brain hurts... Also, I use it in main.cpp: Settings sets; QObject* saveConfig=sets.findChild<QObject*>("saveSetupsButton");

Comment: Well, it might be interessting to know something about your application's structure. For me it looks like, that your `settings` should be a child widget of your `MainWindow`, your `MainWindow` will show or open it after some click on a button, right? So why create it in your main.cpp?

Comment: @MartyFoxy You got an error `invalid use of non-static data member settings::ui' Ui::settings *ui` because you were trying to access it statically even though it is not a static variable. But you shouldn't even be doing that. You should create public functions in your `settings` class that will do what you want with the `ui` members. Don't try to make the `ui` variable public. See [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm).

Comment: What you show is a member variable held by value, it has nothing to do with the stack. If you allocate an instance of `settings` on the heap, then the `ui` is on the heap, just that you don't separately allocate it there, and that's good.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make it static, You can try below :

In your page.cpp :

```
Ui::settings *settings::ui = 0;
settings::settings(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Or if code above does not work, try below :

```
Ui::settings *settings::ui = new Ui::settings;
settings::settings(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

And my question is still why do you want to make it static? What do you want to achieve actually? If you want to manipulate the UI, you should do it inside your settings widget, this is not good practice. If you find something wrong on your UI, it kind hard to find because everything able to manipulate it.